# Android - add next and prev button to softkeyboard which appears on click of an edit text in my activity

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I need to add the NEXT and PREV button to my soft keyboard which appears on clicking on an edit text field in my activity page. Kindly provide me with the pointers for tutorials on implementing this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in xml by

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

or by programatic by

```
yourEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

Comment: My requirement is not to add either next/ prev button. I want to add both such that it appears on top of soft keyboard.

Comment: You cannot have both next and prev. You can have next and done but not next and prev. Just check this url. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

Answer (score 1):

There is method for EditText

```
myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

By using above method you can add Next Button to soft keyboard.

You can refer the link for more information
[For more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

Comment: My requirement is not to add either next/ prev button. I want to add both such that it appears on top of soft keyboard.

Comment: @Saras have you found solution for this problem. if yes kindly provide the solution because now im facing the same issue.

Comment: @SivakumarPurushothaman, You can add only one button at a time. Not both. That was my conclusion. If you find any other answers, please post

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me.