# how to use 2 different ime option of soft keyboard

Tags: android

> i want to show both because i have 3 edit text and in 2 second edit text i want to show both option on soft keyboard so that user can go to previous or next edit text, is there anyway to do this? here is my code can

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/etxtrunner"
 android:layout_width="180dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtrunner"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtrunner"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/qrcode_img"
 android:background="@color/gray"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:imeOptions="actionNext"
 android:ems="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate, yet, you can see that you can not have both next/previous button together [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110620/next-previous-done-buttons-above-keyboard).

However, you can make a makeshift solution  [like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8784028/609782)